# Is there some standard configuration method to disable some features in the android app I am writing?

Tags: android

I am writing my first android app. It is a Unit Convertor. I planned to give four types of conversions in v1.0. While two of those are working fine, two more are not.

I want to release it with the two which are working first. But don't want to delete the code written for the buggy conversions.

While I can use my VCS for such purposes, I wanted to know if there is a way to control the availability of a feature using some configuration or something. I could not find any such reference online. But don't think I am the first person who has come up with such a need.

Is there some standard way of doing this? If so, can someone point me to it?

Comment: Just remove the UI elements of the features which are not working. The functionality will still exist, it just will not be accessible to the user.

Comment: It causes problems because my code refers to them (R.id.xxx) to add listeners for them.

Comment: Is that really a problem? Your business logic should be completely separate from the UI. And you can always just hide the UI elements by setting the visibility to `View.GONE`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how you're displaying these 'features'  If it's a button you could just change its visibility to Gone in the xml:

```
    <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />
```

Comment: Most probably a feature will have more than just one button. It might have a complete set of views, a different layout etc. Setting all of them to gone and all of them to visible everytime you update your code and want to make it visible to customers, is kind of cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way that I have seen in some organizations is to maintain a separate `Feature` file where they have `public` methods that return whether or not this is supported in the particular version. Say for example,

- inches to cm is available in version 1
- pounds to kilogram is not.

In the `Feature` file, you can specifically mention these.

```
private static int InchesToCm = 1;
private static int PoundsToKg = 2;

public static boolean shouldShowInchesToCm() {
  return InchesToCm <= getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.current_version);
}
```

I hope you get the point. You can set `current_version` separately. And then call these functions to check if or not you should show the `View`. Obviously just removing them by setting their visibility to `INVISIBLE` will work as well, but this is a standard method.